# the most performance efficient way to skip excel rows?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a Java EE WebApplication and I am using a file upload mechanism so after uploading file and sending to my server, I am using apache POI to read excel files and store data in db. the files can be very big sometimes containing alot of data i.e. sometimes more than a million rows in it. So therefore i had the need of a progress bar. for that I applied a custom techinque and now that's causing a performane issue when the files are big.

What I am doing is reading all rows from 0th index each time my method is called and I skip no of rows that are previously saved.

Below is the snippet of my method:

```
   Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
                totalRows.value = firstSheet.getLastRowNum();
                // Insert All Rows From Excel To Source Table
                Row nextRow = null;
                int rowsSaved = 0;
                int rowsSkipped = 0;
                int readRowSize = (int) (((int) totalRows.value * 2.5) / 100);
                while (iterator.hasNext() && rowsSaved <= readRowSize) {
                    nextRow = iterator.next();
                    rowsSkipped++;

                    if (rowsSkipped > (int) rowNum.value) {
                        rowNum.value++;
                        rowsSaved++;
    // save data in db
    }
    }
```

I cannot use the method

```
   firstSheet.getRow(index);
```

because of the limitation that i using a specific library that doesn't allow this method and throws

```
UnsupportedMethodException
```

my libraries is:

```
import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader;
// other poi libraries are
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
```

I am using this library because it allows me to read big excel files.If I used :

```
WorkBook myworkbook = new XSSFWorkBook(file);
```

then it would get stuck on files having size of 8-10mb or above, but then in this case i was able to use the "getRow" method;

the code to read file is:

```
File f = new File(fullPath);
            Workbook workbook = StreamingReader.builder()
                    .rowCacheSize(Constants.READ_ROW_SIZE) // number of rows to
                                                            // keep in memory
                                                            // (defaults to 10)
                    .bufferSize(1024) // buffer size to use when reading
                                        // InputStream to file (defaults to
                                        // 1024)
                    .open(f); // InputStream or File for XLSX file (required)
```

Conclusively, If my files are big and have alot of data i.e. more than a million records then at about 50% i.e. when almost half a million records are saved its gets slower and more slower because it first have to skip rows. I was trying to implement a custom iterator if that can allow me to jump to a specific record but I couldn't find a better solution. The solutions I found was to convert iterator to arrayList and jump to records in custom Iterator class but that coversion will also be a performance head.

So if any one has got a better solution then please share.

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI docs on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) ?

Comment: I had a brief look over you provided link.. it also has sheet.getRow(rowNum); MEthod used which I cannot use as I described above other wise it was quite simple

Comment: [link to library](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader)

Comment: You don't seem to be using Apache POI. I'd suggest you either switch back to POI, or report a bug in that library you're using instead